# Can a circular polariser be used with a UV filter?

Tags: filters, polarizer, uv, filter-stacking

I recently bought a new circular polariser and found an old UV (Haze) filter from the '90s from an old camera of ours.

I was wondering whether there are any adverse effects of combining these two filters together; however I have not noticed any oddities in any pictures that I have took recently (after the addition of the UV (Haze) filter).

Comment: Related: [Does stacking more lens filters decrease overall image quality?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12657/does-stacking-more-lens-filters-decrease-overall-image-quality)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't advocate the use of these two filters together as DSLR's don't really need additional UV filters and for each filter you increase the chances of internal reflections etc. plus the polariser is pretty strong when it comes to cutting through hazy scenes - it seems like an unnecessary duplication.

It used to be a general practice to keep a uv filter on lenses as protection for the front element but these days fewer photographers do so as the lens coatings are more hardwearing.

At very least do a test to see if the uv filter is actually adding any value, and if there's no visible improvement then remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Physically if the screw thingies fit yes, but why would you want it? 
UV dont add much in value and are mostly just basic glass. Most of the time it only degenerates image quality.

So if you need it for protection you could also only use the polariser. Ow great thing to know; your equipment can handle more than youd expect

Answer (score 1):

The polarizing filter is used to cut reflections and darken blue sky making the clouds stand out. It is the most valuable optical filter you can own. It works its wonders, adding vividness without changing the colors of the vista.

While doing this task, it also functions just as a UV filter in that it cuts haze. The UV filter is universally used mainly to protect our precious camera lenses against scratches. The UV cutting benefit is of little value when mounted on a modern digital camera. This is because the digital senor is inherently very sensitive to UV light. The camera maker mitigates by incorporating a UV fitter into the protective cover glass mounted over the imaging sensor.

My advice is, never mount a filter if the harm outweighs the good. A filter adds two polished surfaces that reflect light. Reflected light is stray light.
Stacking filters adds additional surfaces. This reflected light intermingles with the imaging forming rays; thus it is the major contributor of optical flare. Flare can be devastating as it robs the image of some of its contrast.

The circulator polarizer adds four surfaces. The first is a linear polarizer; the second is a retarder to de- polarize. The first does the deed; the second prevents the first from interfering with the automation of focusing and exposure determination, as these can be challenged by polarized light.
Let me add that UV filters only work on far distant landscapes and high altitude aerial photography. They are virtually worthless at close distances.