# What are best brands and (side) effects of UV filters?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, filters, equipment-protection, uv

I just bought a Canon T2i and I'm concerned that I need a UV filter (for protection) and I have some questions.

- What are the best brands of filters?
- What (side)effects filters brings to the table?

Other tips from you pros are very welcome!

Answer (score 5):

**A UV filter will provide protection for your lens at the [expense of image quality](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-a-good-quality-uv-filter)**.

Under *normal* circumstances a UV filter is not needed and **better protection is afforded by using a lens hood**. When the lens is in **eminent danger from flying particles of sand or salt water, then it is time to use a UV filter** since the lens hood will not protect against that.

Tests have been done with plenty of UV filters. Different brands also have different grades. The **better ones within a brand are usually labelled 'Super Multi-Coated'** or at least 'Multi Coated'.

**Hoya** makes the best filters *I have used* but, well, I have not tried all the brands but I stay away from B+W which are not color-neutral as a UV filter should be.

**NOTE** Some shops confuse UV and Skylight filters which add a pink cast to everything unless you use Automatic White-Balance computed by the sensor which will cancel out the cast.

**TIP** Save money on filters buy buying the largest size and step-up-rings to avoid needing one filter-per-lens. The catch is that you use either a filter or a lens hood but not both because the step-up ring gets in the way.

Comment: great comments! I'll definitely look for a hoya filter since i'll be going to the beach soon.

Comment: Other side-effect of the filter can be seen here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11518/where-does-this-reflection-come-from-in-a-long-exposure-shot/11520#11520

Comment: in contrast, I use B+W exclusively (if I use filters at all) because of their consistently superior quality (but maybe that's because I can't get the best Hoya stuff here, while the top end B+W products are readily available). Then again, I never use "lens protectors" as UVs are labelled here, only Skylights, the pinkish cast slightly softening otherwise hard tones to make them more pleasin (and only used when I've a need for that, never as "protection", if it's bad enough to damage a front element, it's bad enough to damage other things as well).

Comment: Even some of the protective aspects of filters are disputable, e.g., a filter is more brittle than the typical (thicker and curved) front elements of lenses and mounted in a fairly thin frame of soft metal, so it is quite prone to breaking from impact and pressure (e.g., if left on when carried in luggage). The shards from a broken filter can place the front element in greater risk of damage. I would suggest that filters not be left on as “protection” unless shooting in a situation where they are actively useful, such as protecting from spray/sand/dust flying around.

Comment: @jwenting - If you like the pink cask of Skylight than that explains why you do not mind the browning one of B+W filters ;) Really, I cant stand either one. I sold all B+W UV and SMC Polarizer filters and threw out the Skylight! Also never used these things for protection except in eminent danger. It did save a $1200 lens in a sand-storm 2 years ago, the filter on the other hand got really scratched up in about 3 mins of exposure.

Comment: @Arkku - Exactly my point. Lens hood for protection and UV for sand and salt-water.

Comment: In addition to sand and salt-water, there could also be sparks, paint and other chemicals (in industrial settings), oil particles (in kitchen air), smoke.

Comment: @Imre - Great additions! Never thought about smoke damaging a lens but I believe it :)

Answer (score 2):

Lens-Tip has [compared 20 different UV filters](http://www.lenstip.com/113.1-article-UV_filters_test.html) (results are [here](http://www.lenstip.com/113.4-article-UV_filters_test_Description_of_the_results_and_summary.html)). Hoya is holding the first three positions, but it also has a model in the middle and another one near the bottom, so brand is not all you need to look at, different models really *are* different.

Other questions have already covered [effects](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/what-effect-does-uv-filter-provide) and [side effects](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-a-good-quality-uv-filter).