# Will I be able to mount a hood over my UV filter?

Tags: lens, canon, filters, lens-hood

I have recently bought a Canon EOS 600D and I want to buy a UV filter to give extra protection to my EF-S 18-55 IS II.

And I additionally want to buy a lens hood as well.

Will I be able to use both at same time?

Comment: Yes, the filter has the same diameter as the lens so it won't prevent you from mounting the lens hood.

Comment: Why would you want to use both? The hood offers better protection and possible enhances, rather than degrades, image quality. The UV filter is unneeded since digital cameras have a UV filter in the stack in front of the sensor. And depending on the scene and the filter in question, a flat filter can cause anywhere from a negligible decrease in image quality all the way to ruining an image. See   http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/39879/15871

Comment: Also    http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/57/15871

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/22887/15871

Comment: Actually hood doesn't give protection against dusts. I want to clean the filtor rather than touching the lens. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: There are mixed opinions on this. I do use a UV filter for protecting the lens. It's also an extra barrier for humid air getting in and condensing on and even inside the lens when the camera has been used in extremely low temperatures and you bring it back into your home. In that case you can screw the filter off outside and then screw it back on outside so that you trap an extra layer of bone dry  air. The lens cap will give extra protection, but it won't prevent humid air from leaking inside, but you then only get condensation on the outside of the filter.

Comment: Or you can actually bag the entire camera and lens before moving from cold air to warm air and let the camera and lens warm up to the new ambient temperature before removing them from the airtight bag.

Comment: Be aware of potential vignetting. Some lenses are so close to their vignetting limits that eg two filters stacked or an (usually nasty) aftermarket hood that screws onto the filter thread will cause vignetting at the corners. This may be subtle enough to be unnoticed until specifically looked for but still enough to lower quality markedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the filter has the same diameter as the lens so it won't prevent you from mounting the lens hood.

Comment: Is this same with 50mm and 55-250mm lenses?

Comment: Yes, and the main issue that requires attention is that you buy the filter with the right diameter. So, you have to look up what the required filter diameter is (for my 50 mm lens it is 67 mm).

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are correct: for this lens, the hood attaches to a bayonet on the outside of the lens, and the filter threads are still clear so that screw-in filters can still be added.

It should be noted, however that this isn't universally true: screw-in hoods are available, and for some lenses this is/was the OEM solution. Also, some filter options -- such as the large square filters from Cokin and Lee are pretty much always going to mean that there's no way for a hood to fit when using these systems. And lastly, if you've got a 77mm filter that you want to put on a lens with a 52mm thread you can use step-down rings to do so -- however I bet the hood won't fit over the large filter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The hood doesn't attach to the filter mount. It attaches to an exterior ring.

You could attach a stack of 20 filters one on the top of another and the hood will still fit.  (Of course you probably shouldn't use 20 filters at once!)

Comment: *Some* hoods attach to an exterior bayonet mount. *Other* hoods attach to filter threads.